# Unix character that signals a new line started

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I want to get all lines that are starting with a specific string, using awk.

I use the following code:
`awk -v string="$string" '$0 ~ " "string {`

if the $string=**abc** it will get all lines that have *space* **abc** *space*
that means the word **abcd** doesn't qualify

But I want to do it for words that are at the begging of the line.
Meaning the `" "string` wont work.
So I need the character/sequence of characters that signal the start of a line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use line start anchor `^`:

```
awk -v string="$string" '$0 ~ "^"string {
```

Comment: And you should be able to use `"(^| )"string"( |$)"` to indicate start of line or blank before the word, and end of line or blank after it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: inside the slashes, `string` is looking for the string `string`, not the variable.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for grep:

```
grep "^$string"
```

but be aware that neither this grep nor the posted awk solutions are looking for a string, they are looking for a regexp.

To look for a line start starts with a string you need:

```
awk -v string="$string" 'index($0,string) == 1'
```

or if you want the string to be surrounded by nothing but blanks, simply:

```
awk -v string="$string" '$1 == string'
```